# Как задать layoutStretch

Tags: qt

Есть пять кнопок, находящихся в горизонтальном лейауте. Как задать `layoutStretch` так, чтобы размеры кнопок находились в пропорции 1:1:1:1:3?

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот так (допустим в конструкторе):

```
setStretchFactor(ui->btn1, 1);
setStretchFactor(ui->btn2, 1);
setStretchFactor(ui->btn3, 1);
setStretchFactor(ui->btn4, 1);
setStretchFactor(ui->btn5, 3);
```